# Lenovo Thinkpad x270 intermittently doesn't recognize external monitor

Tags: debian, x11, monitors

I'm running Debian 11 on a Lenovo Thinkpad x270 with only 1 desktop environment, XFCE. I hot swap this computer and several others into an external monitor. The laptop has both HDMI and USB-C ports, and I've successfully used both for this purpose. The current monitor is an HP Z27k G3, but I have used others and had the same problem.

**Intermittently, the Thinkpad stops recognizing the external monitor.** Usually, the laptop wakes the monitor and, when connected, automatically switches from the laptop screen-only config to the external monitor config. During this bug, the laptop does not recognize that a monitor is connected at all: the monitor stays asleep instead of waking up, as usual, because there is no input.

- I was advised to regenerate /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d, but that file doesn't exist. Moving /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d did not fix the problem (and caused the keyboard to stop working in graphical mode).
- The last time this occurred, I restarted the laptop a dozen times and on one of the reboots, having changed nothing, the screen started being recognized again.
- Vaguely-related posts on Ubuntu.SE suggest configuring X11 manually, but what should I configure it to?

Since this has happened several times, I'm somewhat confident it's not a hardware problem (and the other computers do recognize the monitor and can use the same cords). What else can I try?

**UPDATE**: I was able to get the laptop to connect to a previous monitor (which I had wanted to upgrade from). The connection worked up until the laptop fell asleep; on waking, it no longer found the external monitor. It seems to indicate that screen sleep (not suspension -- I had been watching a video and the sound continued) causes the problem.

xrandr does not find modes for any HDMI output (HDMI-0, HDMI-1, etc.) but the command `xrandr` does occasionally "refresh" both screens and cause the monitor to start working again. (Occasionally as in, sometimes after several reboots.)

Comment: FWIW I have the same issue on MS-Windows (via HDMI) after the monitor goes to sleep. Power cycling the monitor resolves. The issue seems to be that once the monitor goes to sleep, the computer has no way of detecting its presence.

Comment: Unfortunately, the problem is not that the laptop predictably stops recognizing the monitor on sleep. It usually wakes the screen as one might expect. Then it becomes incapable of recognizing the monitor no matter what. I'll add this to the question.

Answer (score 0):

I personally run FreeBSD so manual configuration is a bit different, below is an excerpt from the Debian X11 manpage - https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-handbook/workstation.en.html#sect.x11-server-configuration

> Current versions of X.org are able to auto-detect the available hardware: this applies to the
> video card and the monitor, as well as keyboards and mice; in fact, it is so convenient
> that the package no longer even creates a /etc/X11/xorg.conf   configuration file.
> The keyboard configuration is currently set up in /etc/default/keyboard. This file is used both
> to configure the text console and the graphical interface, and it is handled by
> the keyboard-configuration package. Details on configuring the keyboard layout are available in
> Section 8.1.2, “Configuring the Keyboard”.

It looks like debian can handle the keyboard itself though or at least generate the needed X11 config file - https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-handbook/basic-configuration.en.html#sect.keyboard-config

> Even if the keyboard layout is managed differently in console and graphical mode,
> Debian offers a single configuration interface that works for both: it is based on
> debconf and is implemented in the keyboard-configuration package. Thus the `dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration` command can be used at any time to reset the
> keyboard layout.

#### X11 uses `xrandr` to configure multiple monitors  - https://xorg-team.pages.debian.net/xorg/howto/use-xrandr.html

##### Basic usage

> All outputs may be configured through xrandr. To see the available outputs, just run xrandr:

```
$ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1280 x 800, maximum 4096 x 4096
VGA1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
LVDS1 connected 1280x800+0+0 inverted X and Y axis (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 261mm x 163mm
   1280x800       59.8*+
   1024x768       60.0
   800x600        60.3     56.2
   640x480        59.9
DVI1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
TV1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

> We see 4 outputs: VGA1, LVDS1, DVI1, TV1.
> Only the internal panel (LVDS1) is connected and it supports 4 modes at 60 Hz, 1
> mode at 56 Hz.
> The mode marked with a star (*) is the current mode.
> The one marked with a plus (+) is the preferred one. Most monitors report a
> preferred mode to the driver. And the server/driver will generally choose it by
> default.

### Adding/removing heads dynamically

> The old days where you had to restart X when plugging a new monitor are gone. With
> RandR 1.2,
> you can plug/unplug monitors whenever you want. Running the following line will
> query all outputs and enable them with their default mode:

```
$ xrandr --auto
You may also disable one output using:

$ xrandr --output LVDS1 --off
This may be useful for some buggy application that don’t support multiple outputs well.  
Also, due to CRTC limitations (see the Caveats section below), it is often required  
to disable one output before enabling another since most hardware only support 2 at the same time.
```

There is also a GUI application built around `xrandr` if you'd a graphical interface called `arandr`. To install and run it simply use the below in a terminal

```
$ sudo apt update
$ sudo apt install arandr
$ arandr
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Alas it doesn't. Running the xrandr commands only shows that the laptop does not detect the monitor at all.